# how to upload whole text of a file in a row in mysql through terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bash, shell

How to upload whole text of a text file in a row in database, the text gets divided and is stored in subsequent rows.

This is the code of my SQL file, database name is info containing table named info having two columns des1 and des2 having field VARCHAR(3000):

```
    use info;

    INSERT INTO info (des1) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('eng.txt'));

    select * from(info);
```

I am getting following output:

```
des1    des2
NULL    NULL
```

[I also attatched an image showing output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycxnj.png)

I expect all of the text in the file to be in a single row of the database, this has to be done in terminal

Comment: Unless your file literally ends with the text `end-of-file` this isn't going to work. Read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a problem with how you form the string that is to be inserted. You can do it easily by the help of a programming language.

I am providing a simple solution that would work in Python.

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="password",
  database="db"
)

def fileReadToString(filename):
    result = ""
    with open(filename, "r") as ins:
        for line in ins:
            result +=(line)
    return result

file = fileReadToString('eng.txt')

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO info VALUES (%s)"
val = (file)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "done")
```

Answer (score 3):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is for structured data. For unstructured data use [`LOAD_FILE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file):

```
INSERT INTO info (des1) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('eng.txt'))
```

Comment: still giving same results, each row having text upto a line break in the file, I want whole text in one row. Please help me